# error by installing python library after python upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.10, bitcoinlib

I tried to install python library after python update deleted all of my libraries.Therefore, I installed library called "bitcoinlib" , However, I got this error guys I am afraid of it help me. Also sorry for that the error includes my first language.

```
C:\Users\myName>pip install bitcoinlib
Collecting bitcoinlib
  Using cached bitcoinlib-0.6.4-py3-none-any.whl (327 kB)
Collecting pyaes==1.6.1
  Using cached pyaes-1.6.1.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting scrypt>=0.8.19
  Using cached scrypt-0.8.20.tar.gz (55 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.21.0
  Using cached numpy-1.22.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.25.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from bitcoinlib) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ecdsa>=0.17 in c:\users\austin\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from bitcoinlib) (0.17.0)
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=1.4.28
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.4.36-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from ecdsa>=0.17->bitcoinlib) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.25.0->bitcoinlib) (2022.5.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.25.0->bitcoinlib) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.25.0->bitcoinlib) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.25.0->bitcoinlib) (1.26.9)
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17
  Using cached greenlet-1.1.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (101 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaes, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: scrypt
  Building wheel for scrypt (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for scrypt (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt
      copying scrypt\scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt
      copying scrypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_c_module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_py2x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\test_scrypt_py3x.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\ciphertexts.csv -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      copying scrypt\tests\hashvectors.csv -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\scrypt\tests
      running build_ext
      building '_scrypt' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\crypto
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\scryptenc
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\lib\util
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\alg
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\crypto
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1\libcperciva\util
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-windows-stubs
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.obj
      crypto_scrypt.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.obj
      crypto_scrypt_smix.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.obj
      crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.obj
      scryptenc.c
      scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.c(125): warning C4244: '=': 'size_t'에서 'double'(으)로 변환하면서 데이터가 손실될 수 있습니다.
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.obj
      scryptenc_cpuperf.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util/memlimit.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/lib/util/memlimit.obj
      memlimit.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg/sha256.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg/sha256.obj
      sha256.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -Iscrypt-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.obj
      crypto_aes.c
      scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.c(6): fatal error C1083: 포함 파일을 열 수 없습니다. 'openssl/aes.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.31.31103\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scrypt
Failed to build scrypt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scrypt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Is this occurred by windows defender? or is this only pip error

Comment: Please try to do `pip install scrypt`.  That package needs the OpenSSH library, which you don't have.  Doing the install yourself SHOULD install binary packages.  HOWEVER, the `scrypt` documentation says it only supports up to Python 3.9.

Comment: I got another error by installing scrypt

Comment: Upgrading Python from, say, 3.9 to 3.10, doesn't delete your libraries. It installs the new version alongside the old. The new installation is vanilla with no 3rd-party libraries. Unless you have something drastic on your own, your previous Python installation should still be there with all of its installed modules. Use that. And if you have done something drastic to it, restore from backup.

Comment: I mean node.js installed python automatically, because it wasn't able to detect a python and it installed python in a different directory I think that thing made the error